# How do I export a 16 bit PNG in macOS using the ciContext.writePNGRepresentation(of: , to:, format:,colorSpace:, options:) API?

Tags: swift, png, core-image

Is it possible to export a 16bit image using this API ?

```
ciContext.writePNGRepresentation(of: , to:, format:,colorSpace:, options:)
```

I am able to export 10bit HEIF files using the HEIF10 API

`ciContext.writeHEIF10Representation(of:, to:, colorSpace:, options:)`

These are the parameters being used

```
 let options = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as CIImageRepresentationOption: 1.0 as CGFloat]
 let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
 let imgFormat = CIFormat.RGBA8
```

I tried using CIFormat.RGBA16 but that seems to make no difference to the HEIF export which appears to always be 10bit - as expected.

EDIT:
I tried some additional options that also appear to make no difference

```
let options = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as CIImageRepresentationOption: 1.0 as CGFloat,
                       kCGImagePropertyDepth as CIImageRepresentationOption: 64,
                       kCGImagePropertyPixelFormat as CIImageRepresentationOption: 0x16]
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
        let imgFormat = CIFormat.RGBAh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export 16-bit PNG by passing the `CIFormat.RGBA16` to `writePNGRepresentation(...)`.

HEIF doesn't support 16-bit exports, only 8-bit and 10-bit. For 8-bit, use the `writeHEIFRepresentation(...)` method and pass `.RGBA8` or `.BGRA8` as format. For 10-bit, use the specific `writeHEIF10Representation(...)` method.

Comment: I tried the RGBA16 and it does not seem to do anything, the resulting PNG still shows as being 8 bit

Comment: Hmm, can you please try `.RGBAh`?

Comment: Nope makes no difference

Comment: This is strange. Both `.RGBA16` and `.RGBAh` produce 16-bit PNGs for me...

Comment: How are you checking them to verify they are 16 bit ?

Comment: With _Preview_ on macOS and with `exiftool`.

Comment: That's what I am using - this is very strange then.  macOS 14.1.1 ?

Comment: OK - my bad - turns out I had an older export function and was not modifying the newer function.  Thanks using RGBA16 works fine!